# WPF Image Performance

Tags: wpf, performance, image

I have 2 Image Controls. One to dislay image in thumbnails resolution (70x90), the other one to display image in original/source resolution.
The thumbnails image is resized from original resolution without considering aspect ratio.

My question is which one is produce the better performance?

Use 2 image files (same image, different resolution) for each Image Controls

**XAML**

```
<Image Name="Img_Thumb"/>
<Image Name="Img_Original"/>
```

**Code Behind**

```
BitmapImage bmp_thumb = new BitmapImage();
bmp_thumb.BeginInit();
bmp_thumb.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bmp_thumb.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
bmp_thumb.UriSource = new Uri(thumbnails_directory);
bmp_thumb.EndInit();
Img_Thumb.Source = bmp_thumb;
Img_Thumb.Width = bmp_thumb.PixelWidth;
Img_Thumb.Height = bmp_thumb.PixelHeight;

bmp_ori = new BitmapImage();
bmp_ori.BeginInit();
bmp_ori.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bmp_ori.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
bmp_ori.UriSource = new Uri(original_image_directory);
bmp_ori.EndInit();
Img_Original.Source = bmp_ori;
Img_Original.Width = bmp_ori.PixelWidth;
Img_Original.Height = bmp_ori.PixelHeight;
```

or just use 1 image file (the large one) and load it to 2 different Image Control with custom resolution.

**XAML**

```
<Image Name="Img_Thumb" width="70" height="90"/>
<Image Name="Img_Original"/>
```

**Code Behind**

```
BitmapImage bmp_thumb = new BitmapImage();
bmp_thumb.BeginInit();
bmp_thumb.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bmp_thumb.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
bmp_thumb.UriSource = new Uri(original_image_directory);
bmp_thumb.EndInit();
Img_Thumb.Source = bmp_thumb;

bmp_ori = new BitmapImage();
bmp_ori.BeginInit();
bmp_ori.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bmp_ori.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
bmp_ori.UriSource = new Uri(original_image_directory);
bmp_ori.EndInit();
Img_Original.Source = bmp_ori;
Img_Original.Width = bmp_ori.PixelWidth;
Img_Original.Height = bmp_ori.PixelHeight;
```

Comment: This is a bit of an overly general question that is probably suited to CodeReview. Depending on your scenario you typically will want to load many smaller thumbnails then load the full-size images once one is selected. In these cases having smaller copies of images will be preferable. Smaller images will load faster, and use less memory. If you need to load 2 sizes of each and every image, then loading each once and scaling it to two sizes may be a little faster.

Comment: It is the first scenario. I need to load many smaller thumbnails and several full-size image. I read somewhere about DecodeWidth and DecodeHeight. If I use DecodeWidth and DecodeHeight for thumbnails size image with full-size image as source, is it affected performance in term of load time and memory consuming (is it better than using <Image width="70" height="90")?